# How to get the filters on a route in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I need to know which filters are applied to a specific oute. I've been reading through the api of laravel and I found that there is a method called getBeforeFilters() in the Route class.
[getBeforeFilters()](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Routing.Route.html#_getBeforeFilters)
I don't understand very well how this class works but what I thought about is that I needed to instantiate the Route class to use this function.
If this is correct how can I instantiate it - what parameters do I need to provide and what functions do I need to call-
If not then how can use it

> Note: I tried to look for a constructor function in the Route class to
>   know how to instantiate it but I couldn't find any

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you use it:

```
$filters = Route::current()->beforeFilters();
```

If you want to search for a route you have access to them all:

```
foreach(Route::getRoutes() as $route)
{
    echo 'host';
    var_dump($route->domain());

    echo 'uri';
    var_dump($uri);

    echo 'name';
    var_dump($route->getName());

    echo 'action';
    var_dump($route->getActionName());

    echo 'before filters';
    var_dump($route->beforeFilters());

    echo 'after filters';
    var_dump($route->afterFilters());
}
```

Comment: does the current route mean the route that the browser is currently navigating ?
I need to get a specific route that I am not navigating in my browser

Comment: the last two methods didn't work! 
do you know what is the relation between Route and Router classes?

Comment: Sorry, just fixed and it should work. Router (aka Route::) is the routes manager.

Comment: >In the API the method "getRoutes" is in the Route class
how could I call it from the Route class     
>I couldn't find the domain function in the Route or Router classes  
>there is only a method called getBeforeFilters not beforeFilters  
so it seems that there is something that I don't understand with there functions in the API -

Comment: There's a getBeforeFilters in the RoutesCommand. What is this API you are talking about? Could you please show us some codem, your code? So we understand better what you are really trying to do and how...

Comment: here is the API that I am talking about

[Router API](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Routing.Router.html#18-1639)
 I said that the method **getRoutes** was in the **Route** class but that was a mistake I meant it is in the **Router** class sorry for that.

Comment: What I did was making the same loop you suggested but
in the API of the [**Route** class](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Routing.Route.html#_getAllBeforeFilters) I found the method **getBeforeFilters** so I thought that writing **$route->getBeforeFilters()** should work but actually it didn't and **$route->beforeFilters()** worked

Comment: the reason why I looked at the API is that I thought it should give me the methods that I can use with the routes but it seems that there is something that I don't understand about the API in general.

Comment: but any way you answered my question these were additional problems that came out , thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `php artisan routes` from the command line to get a list of all the routes and their filters.